# Use different implementation versions (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I'm using com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0 in my implementation for Banner and Interstitial, I would like to implement Native ads using [Native Templates](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk). The problem is that these templates use the latest version of admob sdk, when I import the template module, my previous implementations show errors. Means that all my code uses the last version in the new gradle.

My question is how keep the Interstitial and Banner ads using the previous sdk, and have the Native template using the last one?

Comment: Simple answer you can't. Just use the latest version and update your obsolete code.

Comment: That's gonna take a lot of work, Thank you anyways.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.